# App suddenly crashes on an NSLog of my NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray

I have a very strange problem. I've made an app, everything works ok.
But now it suddenly crashes on my `NSMutableArray`.

Here is a screenshot of the situation

[image]

A few days ago everything worked normal. Can it be that this comes because of the update of `XCODE and IOS 7` or is it something else?
Can somebody help me? if you need more detailed information. Please ask.

**EDIT**
The array comes from a mutableCopy of my fetchRequest results.

```
NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
newsArray = [matches mutableCopy];
```

**EDIT 2**

```
    -(void)fetchNews{
        newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[TerbremeDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"News"];

        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"new_id" ascending:NO];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
        NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
        newsArray = [matches mutableCopy];
        [tableview reloadData];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"NewsCell";

    NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tablecellbg.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableArrow.png" ]];
    News *news = [newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"news is %@",news);
    static NSDateFormatter *df;
    static NSDateFormatter *df2;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df2 setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
    });


    cell.lblText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:15.0];
    cell.lblDate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:15.0];

    cell.lblDate.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(154/255.0) green:(202/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:100];

    cell.lblText.text = news.new_title;
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:news.new_datepublished];
   cell.lblDate.text = [df2 stringFromDate:date];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: is newarray allocated

Comment: what is the crash log in console? does it print any reason for crashing?

Comment: Also casting your `id sender` to an `NSIndexPath` is probably a bad idea... what is your `sender` in this case ?

Comment: Add some more info.. Question is not so clear.

Comment: Check the type of error message like is it giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS or what?

Comment: I've allocated the NSMutableArray in my ViewDidLoad. And it is giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0xd).

Comment: i think ur problem lies in first line inside the if condition

Comment: Are you sure `indexPath.row < 5`?

Comment: This is what I get when I log my IndexPath, Indexpath is <NSIndexPath: 0x17d32e10> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

Comment: Where do you get that array? It's a property?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit :)

Comment: Maybe the array contains dangling pointers. More code please.

Comment: show allocation of newsArray

Comment: How do you initiate the segue? Sender being a indexPath seems a bit odd.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I've posted more code. Hope this helps ?

Comment: @Zaph I think that I know how that is working. I am using almost a year the same approach and never had problems until now...

Comment: It seems as if your newsArray is a global variable but not a property.. what happens if you make it an actual property (and access it via self.newsArray)?

Comment: @MarcMosby I've tried it but no effect..

Comment: Show the declaration of `newsArray`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC I would assign the newsArray using the objective c facilities, i.e. the generated accessor method.

So it would be

self.newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];